# get string literals out of const array after flatMap on it

Tags: typescript

I have declared an array as const:

```
const cloudRegionItems = [
  {
    category: 'Google Cloud',
    regions: [
      { value: 'v2018-us-central1', label: 'us-central1' },
      { value: 'europe-west1', label: 'europe-west1' },
    ],
  },
  {
    category: 'Amazon Web Services',
    regions: [
      { value: 'us-east-1', label: 'us-east-1' },
      { value: 'us-west-2', label: 'us-west-2' },
    ],
  },
] as const;
```

Then I want to flatten the regions of above mentioned array. I am doing it like this:

```
const cloudRegionOptions = cloudRegionItems.flatMap((item) => item.regions);
```

But I am getting an error as mentioned here:

```
Type 'readonly [{ readonly value: "v2018-us-central1"; readonly label: "us-central1"; }, { readonly value: "europe-west1"; readonly label: "europe-west1"; }] | readonly [{ readonly value: "us-east-1"; readonly label: "us-east-1"; }, { ...; }]' is not assignable to type '{ readonly value: "v2018-us-central1"; readonly label: "us-central1"; } | { readonly value: "europe-west1"; readonly label: "europe-west1"; } | readonly ({ readonly value: "v2018-us-central1"; readonly label: "us-central1"; } | { ...; })[]'.
  Type 'readonly [{ readonly value: "us-east-1"; readonly label: "us-east-1"; }, { readonly value: "us-west-2"; readonly label: "us-west-2"; }]' is not assignable to type '{ readonly value: "v2018-us-central1"; readonly label: "us-central1"; } | { readonly value: "europe-west1"; readonly label: "europe-west1"; } | readonly ({ readonly value: "v2018-us-central1"; readonly label: "us-central1"; } | { ...; })[]'.
    Type 'readonly [{ readonly value: "us-east-1"; readonly label: "us-east-1"; }, { readonly value: "us-west-2"; readonly label: "us-west-2"; }]' is not assignable to type 'readonly ({ readonly value: "v2018-us-central1"; readonly label: "us-central1"; } | { readonly value: "europe-west1"; readonly label: "europe-west1"; })[]'.
      Type '{ readonly value: "us-east-1"; readonly label: "us-east-1"; } | { readonly value: "us-west-2"; readonly label: "us-west-2"; }' is not assignable to type '{ readonly value: "v2018-us-central1"; readonly label: "us-central1"; } | { readonly value: "europe-west1"; readonly label: "europe-west1"; }'.
        Type '{ readonly value: "us-east-1"; readonly label: "us-east-1"; }' is not assignable to type '{ readonly value: "v2018-us-central1"; readonly label: "us-central1"; } | { readonly value: "europe-west1"; readonly label: "europe-west1"; }'.
          Type '{ readonly value: "us-east-1"; readonly label: "us-east-1"; }' is not assignable to type '{ readonly value: "europe-west1"; readonly label: "europe-west1"; }'.
            Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
              Type '"us-east-1"' is not assignable to type '"europe-west1"'.
```

Here is the playground: [TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/MYewdgzgLgBMA2ICuATASgUwOYEtwEkoMBbCGAXhgG0BYAKBhgG97HHgBDIrEAJwE8AXDADkAcRAgs8DDADCiVCIA0rNr2x5Iw2gzaMmMAG4d4SDMJFGATAAYAjAA4AtEgjPgGMFF6n7KmHgOACMMeEs3Dy8fPxEYAF9VPX1DEzMLUQwkXhAABwxnAHcMaH9lQJCwyyyc-KKSqH8EpP0AXRbmtRZkuC5sPiFRAEFiDgAvcBgAdQxgmABlDF4jHE8IFTVGDVxwCB1NtlTTcwj3DA5oZzKK0PDRSPPLpsSDg2NjjJFI4svrAKDbqd6r84i8eu01GDWjALnBdlAANz0eigSCwBDIdCacAAeVyUC0ZEoGNQmB2YEIJAgADoAGZBKAAWQ4uQAFKycERiABKCgAPhgnJI1O2hO5SLo9Cg-HyMA0ECQ8FglFZ0vyIFpcEUWPJeIJu25VDASGIoV4rSoVg%20IlaEqAA)

Comment: Consider mapping then flattening instead of flat-mapping: https://tsplay.dev/mZZram

Comment: I don't know Typescript; it looks like you can also do `cloudRegionItems.flatMap((item) => [...item.regions])` for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you `flatMap` `item.regions`, the resulting type is a mutable array type. Since `item.regions` is a readonly tuple type, the assignment is broken, and an error occurs. You can easily get around this by mapping first, then flattening (which is the same as `flatMap`):

```
const cloudRegionOptions = cloudRegionItems.map((item) => item.regions).flat();
```

This works since the result from `map` is inferred as an array of readonly tuples, and since all `item.regions` are readonly tuples, the assignment works. After you map, you can then flatten the array, which produces the desired result.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/MYewdgzgLgBMA2ICuATASgUwOYEtwEkoMBbCGAXhgG0BYAKBhgG97HHgBDIrEAJwE8AXDADkAcRAgs8DDADCiVCIA0rNr2x5Iw2gzaMmMAG4d4SDMJFGATAAYAjAA4AtEgjPgGMFF6n7KmHgOACMMeEs3Dy8fPxEYAF9VPX1DEzMLUQwkXhAABwxnAHcMaH9lQJCwyyyc-KKSqH8EpP0AXRbmtRZkuC5sPiFRAEFiDgAvcBgAdQxgmABlDF4jHE8IFTVGDVxwCB1NtlTTcwj3DA5oZzKK0PDRSPPLpsSDg2NjjJFI4svrAKDbqd6r84i8eu01GDWjALnBdlAANz0eigSCwBDIdCacAAeVyUC0ZEoGNQmB2YEIJAgADpRrkABT0nBEYgASgoAD4YMySNTtoTWdSAGZBKD01lIuj0KD8fIwDQQJDwWCUeky-IgIVwRRY8l4gm7VlUMBIYihXitKhWD4iVqSoA)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what I'm doing in Typescript but both of the following seem to work in the playground:

```
const cloudRegionOptions = cloudRegionItems.flatMap((item): Readonly<Array<any>> => item.regions);
```

and

```
const cloudRegionOptions = cloudRegionItems.flatMap((item) => [...item.regions])
```

Answer (score 0):

`.map(...).flat()` is the best way to work around this, but an alternative declaration for `flatMap(...)` can also infer the correctly narrowed type:

```js
interface ReadonlyArray<T> {
    flatMap<U extends (unknown | ReadonlyArray<unknown>), This = undefined> (
        callback: (this: This, value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U,
        thisArg?: This
    ): U extends ReadonlyArray<unknown> ? U : U[]
}
```